# MYSQL - additional analysis on sum(field) grouped by name

Tags: mysql

I have an orders table with the following fields : `id, name, price_paid`

The easiest part is this:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    SUM(price_paid) AS total_price_paid 
FROM 
    Orders GROUP BY 
name
```

How should I modify my SQL statement so I get the following at the output?

```
name, total_price_paid, purchase_level
```

Where purchase level would be:

- 1 if total_price_paid is in the range of 0 - 100
- 2 if in a range 101-350
- and 3 if above 350

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    SUM(price_paid) AS total_price_paid,
    CASE WHEN SUM(price_paid) BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN 1
         WHEN SUM(price_paid) BETWEEN 101 AND 350 THEN 2
         WHEN SUM(price_paid) > 350 THEN 3 END AS purchase_level
FROM 
    Orders 
GROUP BY 
    name
```

Comment: Thank you, haven't seen such "case when" constructions before, but they definitely come to rescue this time. Tested your solution and it gives me the results I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional sum:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  SUM(IF(price_paid BETWEEN 0 AND 100, price_paid, 0)) AS sum_0_100,
  SUM(IF(price_paid BETWEEN 101 AND 350, price_paid, 0)) AS sum_101_350,
  SUM(IF(price_paid>350, price_paid, 0)) AS sum_350_plus
FROM 
  Orders 
GROUP BY 
  name
```

Or else, with level:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  SUM(price_paid),
  CASE
    WHEN price_paid BETWEEN 0 AND 100 THEN 1
    WHEN price_paid BETWEEN 101 AND 350 THEN 2
    WHEN price_paid>350 THEN 3
  END AS level
FROM 
  Orders 
GROUP BY 
  name,
  -- don't forget group then:
  level
```

Difference between those two queries are that fires will result in pivot while second will result in plain rows grouping.

Comment: I think in first `price_paid` should be replaced by 1, 2 in SUM()

Comment: Well, first query will result in pivot (that's an option). While second will group rows in plain way

Comment: Hmm,.. thanks for the answer, first select definitely is not what I was looking for, ... second - not sure why would I want to group by level? To me - it looks like answer that was provided by FancyPants does this in most precise way.. correct me if i am missing something and am actually wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Because I assumed you want to sum be level among names.

Comment: no no, my apologies if i was not precise with the question. The idea was to gather each customer's total amount that he has spent and then based on those totals - assign particular purchaser level (again individually for each customer). Definitely not summing those levels.

Comment: Oh, then I was wrong. Thus, I'll not edit my post since correct answer already exists

Comment: Anyway, truly appreciate your input too! Thank you very much!